# How to create a frameless, draggable window in Webview2 + WPF using CSS drag styles

Tags: wpf, electron, draggable, webview2

I'm migrating an Electron application to WPF + Webview2.

In my Electron app, I have frameless windows. Creating a custom, draggable titlebar amounts to adding a CSS property on the `div` that I want to be draggable: `-webkit-app-region: drag`

Example below:

main.js:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(_ => {
    return {
      action: "allow",
      overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
        frame: false
      }
    }
  })
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

index.html:

```
<button onclick="window.open('index2.html')">Open Frameless Window</button>
```

index2.html:

```
<div style="-webkit-app-region: drag; background-color:green">Toolbar</div>
<div>Body</div>
```

In my Webview2 app, I have:

```
public static async void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = e.GetDeferral();

    var win = new Window();
    win.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None; // remove the border
    win.Show();

    var w = new WebView2();
    win.Content = w;
    await w.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(MainWindow.Webview.CoreWebView2.Environment);
    
    e.NewWindow = w.CoreWebView2;
    obj.Complete();
}
```

The window correctly appears without the border, but the custom titlebar is not draggable. It seems like the CSS styles aren't being seen or something.

How can I make those styles have an effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView2 doesn't support the `webkit-app-region: drag` style. You'd need to implement draggable regions yourself manually as described in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/200).

If you'd like you can [open a feature request on our WebView2Feedback project](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues).

Answer (score 2):

FYI, for anyone going through the same pain that I was, WebView2 does now support this: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2243#issuecomment-1448819425

You will just need to pass in the additional argument `--enable-features=msWebView2EnableDraggableRegions`

Comment: oh neat - will test this out in the next couple weeks to check